# how to filter between date in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, date, codeigniter-3

i have a problem , how to filter between date if i only have one column date in my table ?

this is my model

```
public function filter_date ($first_date,$second_date) {
$this->db->where('tanggal >=',$first_date); 
$this->db->where('tanggal >=',$second_date);
return $this->db->get('kegiatan');
}
```

this is my controller

```
   public function filter($first_date,$second_date) {
        $this->load->model('M_kegiatan');
        $data['kegiatan'] = $this->M_kegiatan->filter_date($first_date,$second_date);
        $this->load->view('beranda', $data);
    }
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: If you don't post here any code you will wait for ever for a possible answer. Nobody can read in your mind. So be kind and try to do it good :)

Comment: thanks for your advice , i already edit my post . can you help me to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

try the following piece of code;

```
$this->db->where('DATE(tanggal) >=',$first_date); 
$this->db->where('DATE(tanggal) <=',$second_date);
```

Comment: An explanation of how this will solve OPs problem would make it a much more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know which are your filter requirements but if you want to filter dates that are between a certain range e.g. 'tanggal' has to be greater or equal then $first_date and less or equal than $second_date you could do it so:

```
$this->db->where('tanggal >=',$first_date); 
$this->db->where('tanggal <=',$second_date);
```

If this is not what you mean than some more additional information and clarity it will be needed

Comment: i want to filter tanggal i mean , in my table just have one column to filter, tanggal in english mean date

Comment: So you need the dates that are between the two ranges?

Comment: Then the correction I have made in your code here above must work for you.

Comment: Keep also in mind that will be better if in your model you will return false is the date is not found in the requested range or return the data if some record were found, otherwise `$data['kegiatan']` will be empty and you will get problem in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `between` as below:

```
public function filter_date ($first_date,$second_date) {
  $this->db->where("tanggal BETWEEN $$first_date AND $second_date");
  return $this->db->get('kegiatan');
}
```